# Prove $\sup(|f|) - \inf(|f|) \leq \sup(f) - \inf(f)$ for bounded function $f$ on set $S$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value, supremum-and-infimum

The supremums and infimums are taken on set $S$.

I managed to show that for all $x, y \in S$, we have $|f(x)| - |f(y)| \leq \sup(f) - \inf(f)$. But I didn't see a clear way to proceed.

Comment: Draw a graph. It is immediate.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a rigorous proof though.

Comment: That last comment makes it seem as if you are looking for someone to give you the answer, which is different. If you actually understand why the inequality holds, which should be clear once you draw the graph, then you will see how to write the proof.

Comment: I dont think this question is off-topic. The poster asked how to prove the inequality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\inf f\ge0$ then $|f|=f$ and the claim is clear.
Similarly, if $\sup f\le 0$ then $|f|=-f$ and the claim is also clear (using $\sup(-f)=-\inf f$ etc.)
So assume $\inf f<0<\sup f$.
Clearly  $\inf(|f|)\ge 0$.
If $\sup(|f|)>\sup f$, then $\sup(|f|)=-\inf f$ and we have $-\inf(|f|)\le 0< \sup f$, whence the claim.
If $\sup(|f|)\le\sup f$, then $\sup(|f|)-\inf (|f|)\le \sup(|f|)\le\sup f\le \sup f-\inf f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a set $T$ and a function $g:T\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose we can prove that
$$g(x)\leq a$$
holds for all $x\in T$. Let be $M = \sup g$. Is $M\leq a $ also?

There exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_n\subset T$ with the limit $M$ and $x_n\leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (by definition of supremum).  If $M>a$, then $\varepsilon =M-a>0 $. By definition of limit, at least one $x_{n_0}$ falls into interval $(M-\varepsilon/2,M+\varepsilon/2)$. Since $a <M-\varepsilon/2 < x_{n_0} $, we come to a contradiction. Therefore $M\leq a$. Analogically: if $g(x)\geq a'$, then $\inf g \geq a'$.

Now, you just apply these two facts to your LHS.